# How to make an embed with all the channels and roles with mention

Tags: discord.js

Im fairly new to making bots so I dont know how collections work and I need an embed that shows me all the channels and roles with mention. Its part of a !serverinfo command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the embed by doing this for
Channels

```js
const channelinfo = [];
const keys = Array.from(message.guild.channels.cache.keys())
for(let i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++){
   const channel  = message.guild.channels.cache.get(keys[1])
   channelinfo.push(`Channel name: ${channel.name}\nChannel mention: <#${channel.id}>`)
}
message.channel.send(`Channelinfo:\n` + channelinfo.join(`\n`))
```

And same for Roles^^

Comment: I think instead of 1 being the index it should be "i" but I get it

Comment: I tried it today but I cant get the role mention working